# How to calculate the mean of values for each cell in the matrix, if each cell contains a list with those values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe in size 20x20 (type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame). Each of 400 cells in the dataframe contains a LIST with values. I want to calculate the mean of values for each list (cell) separatly. The dataframe looks like this:

```
      x          y       z ...
x [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]

y [8,2,6,4] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]

z [1,2,4,9] [1,2,4,3] [1,2,4,3]
.
.
.
```

And i want to get result like this:

```
    x    y   z ...                       x     y    z ...
x [10] [10] [10]                       x 10    10   10
                                       y 20    10   10
y [20] [10] [10]       or this:        z 16    10   10
                                       .
z [16] [10] [10]                       .
.                                      .
.
```

My question is, how to calculate the mean for each cell/list with values in the matrix?

Comment: Why do you have lists in a DataFrame like that? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 0):

By matrix, if you mean a pandas DataFrame, and by cells of 400, I assume you mean 400 columns and rows (or one of these). In pandas (python), you can compute a mean like so:

```
dataframe['x'] = dataframe['x'].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))
```

Here **.apply()** lets you apply the function over an entire column or dataframe, and **lambda** lets you iterate through each row. the value **x** is a cell (list), on which you can use python functions like sum() and len() for calculating mean/average.

There's several other ways of doing this as well, but let me know if this helps.

> UPDATE FOR ALL COLUMNS:

A quick way to do this for all of your dataframe columns would be:

```
for column in dataframe.columns:
    dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to apply a function to each cell of a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

dfmean = df.applymap(np.mean)
print(dfmean)

   col1  col2  col3
0   2.5   2.5   2.5
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[1,2,4,3]], 'col2': [[1,2,4,3]],  'col3': [[1,2,4,3]]})
```